# How to render media shortcodes e.g [[fid:1234]]

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database, media

I've written a custom database query to pull out taxonomy data in a specific way, the problem is embedded media shortcodes are outputting the shortcode strings as they stand in the database, rather than the content they represent.

e.g:  `[["fid:"1234"]]` instead of `<a href="/link-to-pdf/file.pdf">pdf</a>`.

**The taxonomy body field can contain:**

- Embedded nodes (`[[nid:1]]`)
- links to other content (`node/nid`)
- **embedded media etc: pdfs** (`[["fid":"6247" "other_props":....]]`)

I've written regex to parse out the first 2 bullet points, and call `_node_embed_replacements()` & `drupal_get_path_alias()` respectively to insert the correct content for them, but i'm having a hard time working out where media module renders embedded shortcodes such as `[["fid":"6247"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [`load_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load/7.x) and `field_view_file()` functions which worked a treat for me. I bundled them with a regex search and replace.

Rough abstract taken from my code not tested but the theory remains the same.

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[{"fid": ?"([0-9]+)".*?\]\]/', $tax_body, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $index = > $fid) {
  $file = file_load($fid); //load the file
  $content = file_view_file($file); // turn it into a render arrray
  $replacement= drupal_render($content); // render it into html string
  str_replace($matches[0][$index], $replacement, $tax_body);
}
```

Perform a regex for `[[{"fid":(???) ..]` where the ??? is the file id that is captured in the `$matches[1]`.

Loop through all found instances, lookup the file markup, and then do a search and replace on the entire string replacing the full shortcodes (matches[0]) with the replacement markup.